# How to download generated pdf file from webapp and attach it to test results in Visual Studio using Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I'm automating a web app using selenium c#, and one of the requirements is to attach an generated PDF file to the test results file in visual studio. I'm able to download the PDF by clicking on the respective button.
Note that I don't have the download link URL since the PDF is generated at run time using JavaScript calls.
So please help me with this question.

Comment: So you want to read whats in the .pdf file am I correct?

Comment: Yes, i also wanna read whats in the pdf to compare the data with the expected values, but my main question is to upload the file to the Test Results file just like we can attach an image.

Comment: What you mean by upload?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a simple solution, checkout the tika package, really straight forward for reading pdfs.

```
from tika import parser

raw = parser.from_file('sample.pdf')
print(raw['content'])
```

Multi - page pdf can be extracted as text at single stretch instead of giving individual page number as argument using below code

```
import PyPDF2
import collections
pdf_file = open('samples.pdf', 'rb')
read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
number_of_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()
c = collections.Counter(range(number_of_pages))
for i in c:
   page = read_pdf.getPage(i)
   page_content = page.extractText()
   print page_content.encode('utf-8')
```